# An error occurred after updating Visual Studio Code and Python

Tags: python, json

I recently updated my Visual Studio Code to version 1.13 , as well as my Don Jayamanne Python 3.6 to the latest version and each time i run the debug console it gives me this error on top...

" Failed to launch the Python Process, please validate the path '${config.python.pythonPath}' " " Open launch.json "

and a separate error on the debug console itself...

" Error: spawn ${config.python.pythonPath} ENOENT "

1. What exactly do i have to validate in the launch.json?
2. And why do i get that error in my debug console?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue, since the upgrade to 1.13.
Solved it by removing the following line from the projects launch.json:

```
"pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
```

I do have python set in my workstations PATH, so I guess even the line

```
   "python.pythonPath": "c:/python27/python.exe",
```

from settings.json might be safe to delete.

note: didn't happen on my MacOS vscode...